# Installing Subversion on Eclipse 2019-09

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, subclipse, subversive

I've installed the latest version of Eclipse (2019-12) and I'm unable to find the SVN connectors in the marketplace. Searching for SVN does not return Subversion or Subclipse and if I try to install them from their website I get a "not compatible with this version of Eclipse."

I installed the previous Eclipse version (2019-09) from where I was able to install it a few weeks ago and I get the same result.

Am I doing something wrong or is did something change with subclipse? Is there an alternative for browsing SVN repositories?

Answer (score 1):

You should download the latest stable subversive release zip file on:

https://www.eclipse.org/subversive/latest-releases.php

It is available under the section "Archived Update Site" (at this time Subversive-4.0.5.I20170425-1700.zip)

Then from Eclipse go under Help -> Install new software -> Add -> Archive... -> select the archive you have just downloaded

After installing subversive remember to install the connector under preferences -> team -> svn -> connectors

Cheers

Comment: As of today, the same procedure can be done with Subclipse downloading the release file from https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse/releases. I did it today with Eclipse CDT 2020-06 (I tried the Marketplace but the repository seemed to be broken).